# LAME: what settings for variable bit rate below 64ktbs?

Tags: mp3, lame, audio-converter

**CURRENT SETTINGS:** According to online blogs and testing, use 32ktbs is "fair" for my use:

```
lame -b 32 --resample 22.050 input.mp3 output.mp3
```

**LAME VBR:**
Since size is really an issue, I wish to push further with a Variable Bit Rate solution around 32k. But as far as I see, [VBR settings](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME#VBR_.28variable_bitrate.29_settings) start at `-V 9` aka around 65k, with the range of 45...85k :

[image]

**WANTED SETTINGS:**

**How to have VBR around 32k ?**  (preferably with LAME's command line)

Comment: A solution recommended online is, for low ranges, to use Average Bit Rates such --abr 56, or --abr 32 for my case. See [Recommended settings#small size for voice](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=LAME#Very_low_bitrate.2C_small_sizes:_eg._for_voice.2C_radio.2C_mono_encoding_etc.). The size of -b 32 and --abr 32 should be roughly the same, but with a better audio quality with --abr. While ABR is an option, VBR should also be available and give better result at this range.

Comment: Does `lame -v -b 0 -B 48 a.wav a.mp3` may do the trick. Testing soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
lame --abr 24 -mm -h -c --resample 22.050 input.ogg output.mp3  #V11
```

Worked very well to keep human voice with good quality (equal to 56kbts), taking silences down to 8kbts (lower limit), for an overall average bitrates of 24kbts. It is kind of like V11.